# Метод сортировки "Шейкерный" (C++)

Tags: c++, сортировка

Есть такая задача:

> Сгенерировать массив и вывести его на экран. Сделать сортировку
>   элементов: Шейкерный. Направление сортировки: по убыванию. Метод
>   поиска: бинарный.

У меня есть следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// функция для обмена значений ячеек
void swapEl(int *arr, int i)
{
    int buff;
    buff = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
    arr[i - 1] = buff;
}

// функция "шейкер"-сортировки
void myShakerSort(int *arr, int size)
{
    int leftMark = 1;
    int rightMark = size - 1;
    while (leftMark <= rightMark)
    {
        for (int i = rightMark; i >= leftMark; i--)
            if (arr[i - 1] > arr[i]) 
                swapEl(arr, i);
        leftMark++;


        for (int i = leftMark; i <= rightMark; i++)
            if (arr[i - 1] > arr[i]) 
                swapEl(arr, i);
        rightMark--;

        cout << "\nИтерация: " << leftMark - 1; // просмотр количества итераций
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    int size = 0;
    cout << "Размер массива: ";
    cin >> size;
    int *A = new int[size];

    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
    {
        A[k] = size - k; // запись значений по убыванию
        cout << A[k] << " | ";
    }

    myShakerSort(A, size); // сортировка

    cout << "\nМассив после сортировки:\n";
    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
    {
        cout << A[k] << " | ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Как его переделать под эти условия?

Comment: кого переделать и под какие условия?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сортировать по убыванию просто  нужно поменять знак сравнения

```
void myShakerSort(int *arr, int size)
{
    int leftMark = 1;
    int rightMark = size - 1;
    while (leftMark <= rightMark)
    {
        for (int i = rightMark; i >= leftMark; --i)
            if (arr[i - 1] < arr[i]) swapEl(arr, i);
        ++leftMark;


        for (int i = leftMark; i <= rightMark; ++i)
            if (arr[i - 1] < arr[i]) swapEl(arr, i);
        --rightMark;


    }
}
```

P.S. и вместо постинкрементов всегда лучше использовать преинкремент, если это не помеха программе. В данном случаи  у вас нет необходимости в использовании постинкрементов

Comment: Чем преинкремент лучше постинкремента?

Comment: эффективностью _  постинкремент создает временный обьект, а в цикле создается каждый раз

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, [хм](https://imgur.com/a/XPyqhtt), тоже слышал об этом много раз, на самом деле, но где можно увидеть это на практике, можно ссылочку или пример, если не сложно.

Comment: @Lex Marchenko , комрилятор  убирает из фрейма временную переменную, но это не значит, что ее не было, и компилятор не выполнил эту оптимизацию. Если возможно  не обременять компилятор лишней работой по оптимизации,  при этом не записывая лишнный код, то  почему это не сделать?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, если оптимизация производится средствами компилятора, то есть ли смысл в этой записи в реальном коде и можно пример, где компилятор не сделает этой оптимизации?

Comment: если время компиляции не критична, то нет проблем, но  лучше привыкать к хорошему стилью программирования

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, ну, хороший стиль дело спорное, особенно говоря о постфиксном и префиксном инкременте. Раньше я использовал исключительно префиксный, руководствуясь тем правилом, о котором говорите Вы, но сейчас (мое сугубо личное мнение), я бы предпочел использовать постфикс, в силу читабельности. А префиксный вариант использовать только в случаях, где без него нельзя, хотя таких я вижу мало.

Comment: Не соглашусь по поводу читабелности. Совсем наоборот: префиксным вариантом вы говорите, что сначала выполняете операцию, а потом используете. Что лучше говорить: "это стоит сто плюс один рубль "  или "это стоит сто один рубль " решать вам. Я выбираю второй вариант, особенно что писать меньше и говорить меньше(время компиляции  меньше)

Answer (score 0):

Как уже ответили, достаточно изменить оператор сравнения.

От себя дополню, что функция swapEl(...) не нужна, т.к. в стандартной библиотеке она уже реализована: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/

Причем в стандарте С++11 работает через move-семантику.

В итоге весь код сводится к этому:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//ф-ция "шейкер"-сортировки
void myShakerSort(int *arr, int size)
{
    int leftMark = 1;
    int rightMark = size - 1;
    while (leftMark <= rightMark)
    {
        for (int i = rightMark; i >= leftMark; i--)
            if (arr[i - 1] < arr[i]) 
                swap(arr[i], arr[i - 1]);
        leftMark++;


        for (int i = leftMark; i <= rightMark; i++)
            if (arr[i - 1] < arr[i]) 
                swap(arr[i], arr[i - 1]);
        rightMark--;

        cout << "\nИтерация: " << leftMark - 1; // просмотр количества итераций
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    int size = 0;
    cout << "Размер массива: ";
    cin >> size;
    int *A = new int[size];

    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
    {
        A[k] = size - k; // запись значений по убыванию
        cout << A[k] << " | ";
    }

    myShakerSort(A, size); // сортировка

    cout << "\nМассив после сортировки:\n";
    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
    {
        cout << A[k] << " | ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: в стандарте сортировка  тоже есть, причем любого вкуса, это не значит, что никто не должен писать их. Кто то учится, а кому то просто интересно, а кто то может написать и получше.  Еслиб никто не писал сам ничего,  стандарт не улучшался бы  с годами

Comment: А если пользоваться стандартом, то вообше ничего не нужно писать, кроме как       sort(A, &A[size], std::greater<int>());

Comment: Загнался что то я под вечер. Все верно. Просто подумал, вдруг про std::swap(...) человек не знает.